# Basic image manipulation (open, copy, crop, paste) in Java or Android

Tags: java, android, python

I'm creating an android apps that use basic image manipulation (open image,copy, crop, paste).

Basically, the program will have multiple image input and it will be manipulated(copy, crop, paste). Then, an output image will be saved. I had done this in python using PIL library and would like to do the same using Java.

So, how do i do this in? Can someone point me a good library that have all the features? Thanks.

Comment: [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) might have the features you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this makes your work on this easy. I was going through some links and found this.

Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks.[Image Manipulation in Java](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/ultimate-image/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That article explains well on loading and saving images. But unfortunately it does not discuss about cropping and pasting images.